# Why is UDP packet reception seemingly optimized mid-execution?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp

I'm running a client server configuration over Ethernet and measuring packet latency at both ends. The client (windows) is sending packets every 5 ms (confirmed with wire shark) as it should. Yet, the server (embedded linux) only receives packets at 5 ms intervals for a few seconds, at which point it stops for 300 ms. After this break the latency is only 20 us. After another period of about a few seconds it takes another break for 300 ms. This repeats indefinitely (300ms break, 20 us packet latency burst). It seems as if the server program is being optimized mid-execution to read IO in shorter bursts. Why is this happening?

Disclaimer: I haven't posted the code, as the client and server are small subsets of more complex applications, however, I am willing to factor it out if an obvious answer doesn't present itself.

Comment: Are all the packets being received?

Comment: I believe so. I can verify this tomorrow.

Comment: How do you measure a latency of 20 us? Is there any request response? Do you have atomic clocks? What's the size of the datagrams?

Comment: @EJP: I know for sure they are during the 5ms send phase, and I'm pretty sure a few are dropped during the 20 us send phase, but not many.

Comment: @rodolk: I use clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, timespec) to fill the ns member in a timespec and then compare that timespec to the previous timespec. I update the new timespec whenever recvfrom() returns (recvfrom isn't blocking). There is no response request atm. I don't think I'm using an atomic clock; but how would I check? The data of interest is 90 bytes and needs to be sent every 5 ms, but I'm sending 94 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spaced out the measurements to 1 in every 1000 packets and now it is behaving itself. I was using printf every 5ms which must've eventually filled the printf tx queue entirely. This then delayed the execution for 300ms. Once printf caught its breath, the program had a queue full of incoming packets and thus was seemingly receiving packets every 20 us.

Answer (score 1):

This is UDP so there is no handshake or any flow control mechanism. Those 300 ms must be because of work the server is doing in the processing of the UDP messages received. During those 300 ms the server has surely lost around 60 messages that were not read from client.

You might probably want to check the server does not take more than 5 ms in processing each message if it uses one thread to process. If the server uses multi-threading to process the messages and the processing takes some time, even if it takes 1 ms, you might be in a situation where at some point all threads are competing for resources and they don't finish in time to read the next message. For the problem you are describing I would bet the server is multithreaded and you have that problem. I cannot assure that 100% for lack of info though. But in any case, you want to check the time it takes to process messages because you might be dealing with real-time requirements.

Comment: I apologize for not providing more information. There are only two threads in the program, and the other thread (another udp server) wasn't being fed any data. Also, the "processing" that my thread of interest does was commented out when the measurements were taken.